# Sweet Alert no me funciona en énvio de E-mail por PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

Cordial Saludo.

Estoy trabajando con PHP enviando un formulario que el usuario completa por correo.

Todo funciona correctamente y al enviar muestre una alerta sencilla de JS, quiero cambiarla por una de `SweetAlert` pero no me funciona.

ALERTA:

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
```

VERSIÓN MAS LARGA:

```
swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  icon: "success",
});
```

MI PHP:

```
$destinatario = 'correo@prueba.com';

$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Correo = $_POST['Correo'];
$Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];

$header = "Este mensaje es enviado desde el formulario de contacto" . "\n";
$mensajeTotal = $Mensaje . "\nCorreo electrónico: " . $Correo . "\nAtentamente: " . $Nombre;

mail($destinatario, $Correo, $mensajeTotal, $header);
echo "<script>alert('El mensaje se énvio correctamente, pronto estaremos contactando con usted.')</script>";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='Index.html'\", 1000)</script>";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/Estilos.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <form action="Correo.php" method="POST" class="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="txtEmp" type="text" class="validate" name="Nombre" />
                <label for="txtEmp">Nombre completo</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="txtNit" type="text" class="validate" name="Correo" />
                <label for="txtNit">Correo electrónico</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea id="txtMsg" class="materialize-textarea" name="Mensaje"></textarea>
                <label for="txtMsg">Mensaje</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="submit" name="Enviar" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        M.AutoInit();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: El script de sweet alert debes añadirlo antes de la llamada, es decir, tienes primero el php donde llamas a sweet alert pero lo llamas más abajo. Prueba añadiendo el cdn de sweet en el head.

Comment: Ahí pegue todo en en la misma hoja. Pero el Correo.php es por aparte, por eso en el  form en el action llamo a Correo.php